# Freeradius 3.0.25 and special characters in shared secret

Tags: freeradius

i'm facing a problem regarding the shared secret in "clients.conf" file in freeradius server 3.0.25.
I tried to follow the documentation, but with no luck, in particular I'm trying to use the exact example in documentation of the octal representation of the secret "AB":

clients.conf:

secret = "\101\102"

then I run the radtest:

./radtest -x testing password localhost 0 "AB"

in server debug log I find:

"Dropping packet without response because of error: Received packet from 127.0.0.1 with invalid Message-Authenticator!  (Shared secret is incorrect.)"

I tried every combination that come in mind: with or without quotes, with the "-t eap-md5" parameter in radtest, ..

Of course if I write 'secret = "AB" ' in clients.conf everything works, but I need octal representation because a client of ours uses special non printable characters in the secret.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by changing the default value of parameter correct_escapes in file radiusd.conf:

correct_escapes = false <-- it was 'true' by default

Still is not clear to me why it doesn't work with correct_escapes set to 'true', maybe it's a bug?